# Find matching between 2 files (how to improve efficiency)

Tags: regex, perl, grep, compare, match

`@file1` contains only startpoint-endpoint pair, each indices represent each pair. `file2` is a text file, for `@file2` each indices represents each line. I am trying to search each pair from `@file1` in `@file2` line by line. When the exact match is found, I would then try to extract `information1` from `file2` and print it out. But for now, I am trying to search for the matched pair in `file2`. The format of the matching pattern is as below:

#### Match case

#### From `$file1[0]`

```
Startpoint: /source/in_out/map (positive-triggered) 
Endpoint: /output/end/scan_all (positive-triggered)
```

#### match if `file2` contains:

```
Line with other stuff
Startpoint: /source/in_out/map (positive-triggered) 
Endpoint: /output/end/scan_all (positive-triggered)
information1:
information2:
Lines with other stuff
```

#### Unmatch Case:

#### From file1:

```
Startpoint: /source/in_out/map (positive-triggered) 
Endpoint: /output/end/scan_all (positive-triggered)
```

#### From file2:

```
Startpoint: /source/in_out/map (positive-triggered)
Endpoint: /different endpoint pair/ (positive-triggered)
information1:
information2:
```

For text `files2`, I stored it in `@file2`. For `files1`, I have successfully extracted and stored every Startpoint and the next line Endpoint as the format above in `@file1`. (No problem in extracting and storing each pair, so I wont be showing the code for this, it took around 4mins here) Then I split each element of `@address`, which are the startpoint and endpoint. Checking line by line in `files2`, if startpoint match, then I will move on next line to check endpoint, it is only considered match if the next line after Startpoint match the Endpoint, else try to search again until the end line of `files2`. This script does the job but it took 3 and a half hours to complete(there are around 60k pairs from `file1` and 800k lines to check in `file2`). Is there any other efficient way to do this?

I am new in Perl scripting, I apologize for any silly mistakes, both in my explanation and my coding. 
Here's the codes:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my $report = '/home/dir/file2';
open ( $DATA,$report ) || die "Error when opening";
chomp (@file2 = <$DATA>);
#No problem in extracting Start-Endpoint pair from file1 into @file1, so I wont include 
#the code for this 
$size = scalar@file1;
$size2 = scalar@file2;

for ( $total=0; $total<$size; $total++ ) {
   my @file1_split = split('\n',$file1[$total]);
   chomp @file1_split;
   my $match_endpoint = 0;
   my $split = 0;
LABEL2: for ( $count=0; $count<$size2; $count++ ) {
           if ( $match_endpoint == 1) {
              if ( grep { $_ eq "file1_split[$split]" } $file2[$count] )
              print"Pair($total):Match Pair\n";
              last LABEL2;         #move on to check next start-endpoint 
                                   #pair 
              }
              else {
              $split = 0;          #reset back to check the same startpoint 
              and continue searching until match found or end line of file2
              $match_endpoint = 0;
              }
            }
            elsif ( grep { $_ eq "$address_array[$split]"} $array[$count] ) 
           { 
           $match_endpoint = 1;#enable search for endpoint in next line
           $split = 1;         #move on next line to match endpoint
           next;  
           }
           elsif ( $count==$size2-1 ) {
           print"no matching found for Path($total)\n";
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Rather than me trying to use this little comment to guess what you mean when you imply that pairs of lines in `file1` match pairs of lines in `file2`, you should give a sample of lines from both files demonstrating which ones match and which ones don't. Your rules for matching aren't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @jeff6times7 I have included one example for each case

Comment: You may be "new in Perl scripting" but it doesn't take knowledge of the language to indent and lay out your code so that it is readable. It is particularly impolite of you to post such ugly code when you are asking for free help from international experts.

Comment: What do you mean by "_match_" -- want do you want to do with this? You find pairs in the first file. Then, once you find the "same" pairs (they all seem exactly the same?) in the second file ... what do you want to do?  Print line numbers ... ?

Comment: I think you can solve this problem with a hash for each file.

Comment: @Borodin Noted with thanks @zdim yes, they are exactly the same. After the match pair is found in `file2`, I would try to extract and store some data under this pair from `file2` (e.g. time to travel this path etc.) and compare with the data from `file1`

Comment: What do you mean by "_data under this pair_" if they are all exactly the same?  What is "_time to travel this path_"?  (And "_(etc.)_"?  We don't know your problem.)  There are many ways to correlate phrases in two files.  But how, if they are the same?

Comment: Let me put it this way.  So you found the 60k pairs in the first file.  Now you start searching the second ... and you find a pair.  Does it correlate with the first pair from the first file? How about the next one you find?  What if the second file has fewer (or more) pairs?  How do you decide which one from file2 goes with which one from file1? Can you please explain the problem nicely?

Comment: @zdim I have updated the question. Yes, file2 has less pairs than file1, so I decided to extract pair from file1 as I also want to find out the unmatched pair.

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your spec (show matches), I'm betting this will complete in less than 5 seconds, unless you're using an old Dell D333. To further minimize the response time, you would write some extra code to drive the while loop by the hash with the fewest keys (you implied file1). If you use references to hashes, then you can write a small if-else statement to swap the hash references without having to code duplicate while statements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub makeHash($) {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    open(DATA, $filename) || die;
    my %result;
    my ($start, $line);
    while (<DATA>) {
        if ($_ =~ /^Startpoint: (.*)/) {
            $start = $1;    # captured group in regular expression
            $line = $.;     # current line number
        } elsif ($_ =~ /^Endpoint: (.*)/) {
            my $end = $1;
            if (defined $line && $. == ($line + 1)) {
                my $key = "$start::$end";
                # can distinguish start and end lines if necessary
                $result{$key} = {start=>$start, end=>$end, line=>$line};
            }
        }
    }
    close(DATA);
    return %result;
}

my %file1 = makeHash("file1");
my %file2 = makeHash("file2");

my $fmt = "%10s %10s %s\n";
my $nmatches = 0;

printf $fmt, "File1", "File2", "Key";

while (my ($key, $f1h) = each %file1) {
    my $f2h = $file2{$key};
    if (defined $f2h) {
        # You have access to hash members start and end if you need to distinguish further
        printf $fmt, $f1h->{line}, $f2h->{line}, $key;
        $nmatches++;
    }
}
print "Found $nmatches matches\n";
```

Below, is my test data generator([thanks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=233023)). I generated a worst-case scenario of 1,000,000 matches between two equal files. The matching code above finished on my MBP in under 20 seconds using the generated test data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub rndStr { join'', @_[ map{ rand @_ } 1 .. shift ] }

open(F1, ">file1") || die;
open(F2, ">file2") || die;

for (1..1000000) {
    my $start = rndStr(30, 'A'..'Z');
    my $end = rndStr(30, 'A'..'Z');
    print F1 "Startpoint: $start\n";
    print F1 "Endpoint: $end\n";
    print F2 "Startpoint: $start\n";
    print F2 "Endpoint: $end\n";
}
close(F1);
close(F2);
```

Comment: Hi jeff, I cant seems to understand how `$fmt` works here. Also, correct me if I am wrong `f1h` is the contents for `$file1{$key}` ?

Comment: @Kyle Are you wondering why printf works with "%10s" when it's given a integer? It's no mystery: the integer is simply coerced as a string in decimal form. Yes, $f1h is the value for the hash element referred to by $file1{$key}.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding what your code is trying to do,
it looks like it would be more efficient to do it this way:

```
my %split=@file1;
my %total;
@total{@file1}=(0..$#file1);
my $split;
for( @file2 ){
    if( $split ){
      if( $_ eq $split ){
         print"Pair($total{$split}):Match Pair\n";
      }else{
         $split{$split}="";
      }
    }
    $split=$split{$_};
    delete $split{$_};
}
for( keys %split ){
  print"no matching found for Path($total{$_})\n";
}
```